# Text-indent in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am very confused why my text is not indenting.

http://69.143.164.37/csa-consulting/clients.php

The very bottom left "Educational Specifications" is wrapped inside of a p styled as such:

```
<p style="text-indent: 3em">Educational Specifications</p>
```

Why does that not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

because on line 150 of style.css you specified display:inline for  `<p>` elements inside content

```
#content p {
   display: inline;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

just remove that rule

Answer (score 1):

Because the p element is inline here . You can find

```
#content p { display:inline }
```

in your style.css file.

But the indent property only act on block container .

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/text-indent

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-left` instead.

```
style="padding-left: 3em;"
```

Answer (score 0):

the text-indent property doesn't work on inline elements. Try:

```
<p style="display: block; text-indent: 3em;">Educational Specifications</p>
```

That should work for you.